# Is $\langle f \rangle $ an "inner product"?

Tags: notation, inner-products

> Let $$\langle f(x,y)\rangle = \iint_S f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

I have seen the above in multiple papers as the definition of $\langle f(x,y)\rangle$. I would normally associate angle brackets with being an inner product $\langle f,g \rangle$ of two functions $f$ and $g$, but the definition I have quoted appears to be acting on a single function. Is this still defining $\langle f(x,y) \rangle$ as an *inner product*, or is it borrowing the notation of angle brackets resulting in my confusion?

Comment: An inner product takes two inputs, this takes only $f$.

Comment: What I have seen is $\langle f, g\rangle = \int fg d\mu.$

Comment: This is a linear functional.

Comment: In many contexts $\langle A \rangle$ refers to some sort of average or expectation value of an object $A$, and the definition you've quoted is suggestive of this. Indeed, if $S$ has unit area, then $\langle f(x,y) \rangle$ really is the average value of $f$ on $S$.

Comment: It's definitely not an inner product. As Branimir says, it appears to mean something like the expected value of the function $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Often $ \langle f \rangle_\mathcal{F}$ denotes the average or expected value of $f$ over the family/region $\mathcal{F}$.

In my experience, it's typically normalized (but not always) when that makes sense. So if $\mathcal{F}$ is a discrete family, then $\langle f \rangle_\mathcal{F}$ might typically be defined as
$$
\langle f \rangle_\mathcal{F} = \frac{1}{\# \{x \in \mathcal{F} \}} \sum f(x).
$$
If $\mathcal{F}$ is continuous, then it might typically be defined as
$$
\langle f \rangle_\mathcal{F} = \frac{1}{|\mathcal F|} \int_\mathcal{F} f d \mu.
$$
When the domain $\mathcal{F}$ is understood, it is often left from notation.